# How can you index a text search that has only one wildcard at the beginning of the search term ('%TERM')?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I found the following query in our MySQL slow query log:

```
SELECT target_status 
FROM link_repository 
WHERE target_url LIKE CONCAT('%', 'bundle/rpi_/activity/rpi_bridge/bridge_manual.pdf')
```

When I pointed this out to the developer manager in a conversation about slow page loads, he stated:

> come on; concat() is a simple string concatenation and '%' is the wildcard in the search string. I know that searching strings is not the fastest of operations (that's why we have lucene-like engines, but this is trivial stuff)

There's about 18k rows in link_repository, which isn't much. The documentation I'm finding is that indexing on character strings doesn't work with wildcards. Is there an alternative strategy one can use?

Comment: Your manager is trying to sound authoritative.  Ask him what the index would look like, i.e. what entries it would have, since you don't know in advance what the value of `TERM` is.  Say `TERM` is `XYZ`, it would have to be able to find `AXYZ`, `AAAAAXYZBBBBBB` and `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAXYZBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB`.  Challenge him to come up with an indexing scheme for this without knowing in advance the string to be searched for.  That is indeed why Lucene and others exist, but they do so by building multiple indexes.

Comment: Sometimes it's best to disengage; but I will note that it doesn't have to find (.b)*, there's no index. It's a scenario that could plausibly be indexed, by a system clever enough to build an index out of the REVERSE() of the string field.

Answer (score 1):

In order for LIKE to use index it has to start with something. MySQL search from left to rigt. So if the string star with anything then MySQL will do a table scan and no index will work.

However, if you are using InnoDB tables you can try to use [Full-Text Index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html).

You can  add a [Full-Text Index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) on the column, then you can use MATCH AGAINST function to find what you need then you can add `RIGHT()` clause to only give you the results that end with your string.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX target_url ON target_status(target_url);
```

Then you can query the records like so

```
SELECT target_status 
FROM link_repository 
WHERE MATCH ('bundle/rpi_/activity/rpi_bridge/bridge_manual.pdf') AGAINST(target_url) AND RIGHT(target_url, 49) = 'bundle/rpi_/activity/rpi_bridge/bridge_manual.pdf'
```